# changing an alert into a print out

Tags: javascript

I am Still messing with this calculator coded in JavaScript. I'm asking this question on how do I make it so that it stops showing an alert for the output and prints it into the div tag below named "Output".

I've already placed in what I think it would be in the Output and I have pasted this below:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link href="stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript">



    function checkinputs(){
    var     A = parseInt(document.triangleform.input1.value);
    var     B = parseInt(document.triangleform.input2.value);
    var     C = parseInt(document.triangleform.input3.value);


        if (A == B && B == C) { alert("Equalateral"); } 
        if (A == B && B != C || B == C && A != B || C == A && A != B) {alert("Isosceles");} 
        if (A != B && B != C && C != A) {alert("Scalene!");} 
    }



    function keypress(evt) {
      var theEvent = evt || window.event;
      var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
      key = String.fromCharCode( key );
        var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
      if( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    function notEmpty(field, NocharMsg){
        if(field.value.length == 0){
            alert(NocharMsg);
            field.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    </script


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="Container">

    <div id="Header"><h1></h1></div>

            <div id="Content_1">
                    <div id="Explanation">
                    This calculator will determine what
                    triangle you have made depending on
                    the integer values in the input fields.

                    </div>
                    <div id="Form">
                        <FORM NAME="triangleform">
                        Enter the triangle values below: <br>
                        <p>
                        <h4>Side 1: </h4><BR>
                        <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input1" onkeypress='keypress(event)' /><P>
                        <h4>Side 2: </h4><BR>
                        <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input2" onkeypress='keypress(event)' /><P>
                        <h4>Side 3:</h4> <BR>
                        <INPUT TYPE="Integer" NAME="input3" onkeypress='keypress(event)' /><P>
                        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Submit" Value="Submit" onClick="checkinputs()" />
                        </FORM>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Verbal_Output">
                        <h2>You made a:</h2>
                        <p>        
                        <h2>Triangle</h2>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <p>
                <p>
            <div id="Content_2">

            <div id="Output">
            <script>
            document.getElementById("Output").value = checkinputs();

            </script>   
            </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly there - a div doesn't have a `value` property (that's for form inputs), but it **does** have a `innerHTML` property.  Just make sure you `return` the values you want from `checkInputs()`, instead of `alert`ing them.

For example:

```
function checkinputs() {
    var A = parseInt(document.triangleform.input1.value),
        B = parseInt(document.triangleform.input2.value),
        C = parseInt(document.triangleform.input3.value),
        result;


    if (A == B && B == C) { result = "Equilateral"; } 
    if (A == B && B != C || B == C && A != B || C == A && A != B) { result ="Isosceles";} 
    if (A != B && B != C && C != A) { result = "Scalene!";} 

    // return result;
    document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Then in your markup:

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = checkinputs();
</script>
```

Note that `.innerHTML` is case-sensitive.

Comment: So instead of it being `{alert("Name");}` it would be 

  `if (A != B && B != C && C != A) {return;}?`



        `<div id="Image_Output">
  <script>
  document.getElementById("Image_Output").innerhtml = checkinputs();

  </script>   
  </div>`

Comment: Added an example, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I just changed the function to yours (re-wrote it myself to learn) and changed the div to : 

`<div id="Image_Output">
  <script>
  document.getElementById("Image_Output").innerhtml = checkinputs();

  </script>   
  </div>`

Still no change? Or am i missing something? Would it be checkinputs(return);

Comment: Ah, well now you're in to race-condition land! :) The function is run once, on page load, so there's no values in the form inputs and therefore nothing will happen. You could trigger the `innerHTML` setting in a click/submit handler on the form submit button - as in Rahul's example above.

Comment: Completely mind blown now haha, So Can I use this code in conjunction with Rahuls?

Comment: Rahul's answer relies on jQuery and sets the innerHTML (through jQuery's own methods) whenever `checkInputs()` is run. You can use his version but replace `$('#output').html(...)` with `document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = ...`. Example modified above! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkinputs(){  
    var A = parseInt(document.triangleform.input1.value);
    var B = parseInt(document.triangleform.input2.value);
    var C = parseInt(document.triangleform.input3.value);

    if (A == B && B == C) { $('#output').html("<div>Equalateral</div>");}
    if (A == B && B != C || B == C && A != B || C == A && A != B) {$('#output').html("<div>Isosceles</div>");}
    if (A != B && B != C && C != A) {$('#output').html("<div>Scalene!</div>");}
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it would be much more helpful if you could explain why.

Comment: Hey Rahul, thanks for the response. I'd appreciate a explanation if thats ok :)

Comment: Also, there is no jQuery requirement here.

Comment: There is no special need for using Jquery here, it can be done with pure javascript too , the reason it was used is to make minimal changes to the original code.

Comment: and instead of using a return call I would prefer making changes in the function itself. The code looks simple and uncomplicated but if this is a bigger and complex code , I would suggest making use of Jquery to make things simpler.

Comment: For the purposes of this small example I wouldn't use jQuery but yes, going forward it's definitely worth taking a look at. It takes all the pain out of cross-browser DOM manipulation.